# Namespace length

Tags: namespaces, facebook-apps, facebook-page

I'm trying to configure a new application, but my fan page (http://www.facebook.com/fansdeviolettatequiero) have 22 characters and the Namespace in application only lets me put 21 characters, so my Namespace it's wrong and I can't fix it.

My Namespace HAVE to be fansdeviolettatequiero. But stays fansdeviolettatequier

Please let me know what I can do to put my Namespace correctly.

Comment: How did you resolve it?